# Convert CAF file to WAV in Java?

Tags: java, android, wav, caf

We have a large number of Apple Core Audio / CAF files that we'd like to use on our Android client, so it would be helpful to convert from CAF to WAV in Java.

Are there any existing libs or open source projects that can help with this?

Comment: There's this for WAV IO: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html, now just need to read CAF...

Comment: Hi, were you able to find something that does the conversion from .caf to other formats in android programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to do this in Java? If it is a static conversion to WAV (i.e. - you only plan to convert these files once), you should use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert them. If you need to actually convert the files in your Android application for whatever reason, you may be out of luck. It looks like the *only* Java support for CAF was abandoned by Apple over 5 years ago.

Comment: Yeah, it would be beneficial to do the conversion client-side since the CAF files are typically about one-quarter the size of the decoded WAV file.